# Android Studio Como referenciar a Activity dentro de um método Static

Tags: android-studio, firebase, static, this

Precisei criar um método estático na activity principal, pois o Firebase não está aceitando `Framents` dentro do `CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

Gostaria de saber como eu referencio a activity principal dentro do modo `Static`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este código está dentro da `activity_cadastro`, pois dentro do `Fragment`, o Firebase não está aceitando.

Então estou coletando os dados no Fragment (`fragment_usuario`), coloco estes dados (email, senha, etc) dentro de um objeto **Usuario** e passo este objeto **Usuario** por parâmetro para o `activity_cadastro`.

Como o método é `Static`, o **This** não está sendo referenciado.

Comment: Esse método tem mesmo de ser *static*? Ao torná-lo *static* foi criado outro problema. Normalmente, uma solução que cria outro problema não é a melhor abordagem. Não podendo usar *this* "directamente" pode passá-lo ao método. Não sei se será possível e não garante que surjam outros problemas.

Comment: Será mesmo que necessita de uma Activity? Não será um Context que é necessário? Veja [Como obter o context num fragment?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/218942/2541) e [Qual diferença entre os métodos para obter um contexto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180349/2541)

Comment: Pra responder as perguntas: @Ramaral Sim... Precisava ser `Static` porque eu ão estava conseguindo resolver a questão do `Context`por isso eu estava usando um método que criei em outra Activity.

Parece que seu segundo comentário resolveu meu problema. Consegui adicionar o usuário. O Toast não está mostrando o resultado dos erros, mas isso eu vejo em outra ocasião. Obrigado.

Comment: @Ramaral, infelizmente não consigo ou não sei marcar seu comentário como resposta. Mas muito obrigado.